# Titanium : Not able to run the app in device error :[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

Unable to run the app in device getting following error:

[INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=dk.napp.drawer version=latest platform=android deploy-type=test path=D:\Work\Android\APPNAME\modules\android\dk.napp.drawer\1.1.3
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [path](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140526/solution-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination). also please check your log console carefully as you may get clues from warnings